# Printf statement doesn't like my inputs

Tags: java, methods

```
public int maxRate(int maxRate)
    {
        maxRate = 220 - age;

        return maxRate;
    }

    // calculate target rate
    public String targetRate(int targetRateMin, int targetRateMax, String targetRate)
    {

        targetRateMin = (age * (1/2));
        targetRateMax = (age * (17/20));
        targetRate = (targetRateMin + "-" + targetRateMax);

        return targetRate;
    }

    // display message
    public void displayMessage()
    {
        System.out.printf("Name: %s %s"
                + "\n Age: %d"
                + "\n Target Heart Rate: %s"
                + "\n Maximum Heart Rate: %d"
                , getFirstName(), getLastName(), calculateAge(age), targetRate(), maxRate());
    }
```

I am confused as to why I'm getting errors when I try to use `targetRate()` and `maxRate` in my printf statement (I'm getting the red squiggly things telling me to add stuff I don't understand). Are my method's wrong or something?

Comment: Please show your error/exception message. Also, change `\n` to `%n` within your printf format String.

Comment: Your method: `public int maxRate(int maxRate)`; your method call: `maxRate()` ... I _really_ wonder were here the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide valid arguments for the invoked methods.

```
getFirstName(), getLastName(), calculateAge(age), targetRate(), maxRate());
```

For instance, your `targetRate()` and `maxRate()` are having no arguments.

According to your method signature of `maxRate()` and `targetRate()`, you need

- 1 int argument for `maxRate(int)`
- 2 int & 1 String arguments for `targetRate(int, int, String)`

Answer (score 0):

> maxRate()

Takes an integer argument.

Comment: And `targetRate` has the signature `(int, int, String)` and it's being called with no arguments.